# Getting the column value from a table when a checkbox is clicked using handlebars, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I have recently started working on JS, jQuery and Handlebars.js. I am displaying the data I am getting from java on to a divTable. The Handlebars template is shown below

```
<div id = "diffs">
"Others"
  <div class="divTable" id="diffTable">
  <div class="divTableBody">
  <div class="divTableRow">
  <div class="divTableCell">header;</div>
  <div class="divTableCell">header;</div>
  <div class="divTableCell">header;</div>
  <div class="divTableCell">header;</div>
  </div>
  {{#each diffs}}
  {{#diff this.[1]}}
  <div class="divTableRow"  id="diffTableRow">
  <div class="divTableCell column1">{{this.[0]}}</div>
  <div class="divTableCell">{{this.[1]}}</div>
  <div class="divTableCell">{{this.[2]}}</div>
  <div class="divTableCell"><input class="divCheckbox approveCheckbox" type="checkbox" /></div>
  </div>
  {{/diff }}
  {{/each}}
  </div>
  </div>    
  <button class="differences-modal-dismiss"> Cancel </button>
  </div>
```

The handlebars helper is as follows:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('diff', function(var1, options) 
{
    if (var1 !== "someValue") 
    { 
        return options.fn(this); 
    }
    return options.inverse(this);
});
```

What I need is, when a checkbox becomes checked, to get the text of the `.column1` element within the checked checkbox's row. I have the following in my JS:

```
$('.approveCheckbox').click(
    function()
    {    
        meanings.push($('.column1').text());         
    });
```

This is returning value only from the first row, no matter what checkbox is checked. I tried using the `.each()` method but I am not sure I am using it the right way. This is what I was doing with `.each()`:

```
 $('.column1').each(function(){                
            if($("input:checked"))
            {
                alert($(this).text());                    
            }
        });
```

I could use some help in returning the values from `.column1` when its corresponding checkbox is checked. Should I be changing my helper or is there anyway I can do it from jQuery?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems strange that you would use divs instead of table elements.

Comment: I know that's a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't really have anything to do with [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/). Handlebars is for creating template methods that return strings of HTML that can be added to the DOM. The binding to events in that DOM is done afterwards in the JavaScript and, as you are doing, can be aided with a library like [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

With that said, the problem with your click event handler is that it does not provide a scope within which to find the `.column1` element, so it finds the first one on the page and gets its text. What we must do instead is to get the parent of the clicked checkbox, the `.divTableCell`, and then find among that parent's `.divTableCell` siblings the element with class "column1". jQuery has some helpful methods for doing this:

```
$('.approveCheckbox').click(function() {
    meanings.push($(this).parent().siblings('.column1').text());
});
```

The code above will get the correct text, however it will *not* meet your requirement of getting the text corresponding to each checked checkbox. This code will push the text value to `meanings` each time the checkbox is checked or unchecked. You may find the following to be a more appropriate solution:

```
$('.approveCheckbox').change(function () {
    meanings = $('.approveCheckbox')
        .filter(':checked')
        .map(function (index, el) {
            return $(el).parent().siblings('.column1').text();
        })
        .get();
});
```

What the above code does is, on each change to an `.approveCheckbox`, is to get all `.approveCheckbox` elements, filter out the unchecked ones, map the remaining boxes to their corresponding text values, convert the result to a simple array, and assign this array to the `meanings` variable. This way, `meanings` will always reflect the current checked/unchecked state of the table.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/n8assfor/) for reference.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. This is great. Thank you so much for the reply. But, i do have one more question. Is it possible to get thevalue that we are checking for in the handlebars, that is if a particular checkbox is checked we need to get the value of {{this.1}} in to the array and this will not be in the table. the rows will have the values of this.0, this.2, this.3. So, if I check the first checkbox I should get the value of A.One of the first row in the array. Is it possible?? I have updated the fiddle with this. Does this look okay??
https://jsfiddle.net/n8assfor/2/

Comment: @Vinay: I am not sure that I understand what you are asking. Why can't the value at index 1 in each array in `diffs` be in the table? Couldn't you put it in a data-attribute?

Comment: @Vinay: I have tried to understand your requirements and have created an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/xuna6tne/). I have got rid of your `#diff` helper because I couldn't understand what it was intended to do. I am using the value attribute of each checkbox to hold the `{{this.[1]}}` value.

Comment: @7684: I probably should i have mentioned this. I have two tables and one table should have data only with particluar meaning and in the array of diffs the second element is the mening we are checking. so if the meaning lets say is a name, that goes to another table and we dont have to bother about the checkboxes, but if the meaning is anyting else i need this table and for every checkbox checked i need that corresponding meaning to be sent back to java

Comment: @7684: This worked. Thanks. I still need that helper I kept it as is but added the value attribute to the input tag. This is much more easier and better than what I had. Thanks again for the help :)